# Removing or Overriding Vertical-Align in TD tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The issue that I'm having is the `<td>` tag in my table is causing the JQuery time picker I'm using to display `HH:MM` vertically rather than horizontally.  Outside of the `<td>` tag, the time picker displays fine, but inside it displays vertically.  I believe the browser renders the `<td>` tag with a vertical-align property and I was wondering if there is a way to override it, so the `<td>` tag does not use the vertical-align property?

I apologize in advance for the non-embedded images (account restrictions).

Here's how the time picker looks in the table:

[[image: JQuery Time Picker Vertical][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcUci.jpg)

---

EDIT:

Here's some CSS that I'm using for the Time Picker appearance:

[[image: Combined display of each class][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brSqz.jpg)

```
    .time_pick {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 60%;
    }

    .timepicker_wrap {
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 998;
        display: none;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 0 rgba(50,50,50,0.35);
        background: #f6f6f6;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .time,
    .mins,
    .meridian {
        width: 60px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #2d2e2e;
        font-family: arial;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .ti_tx,
    .mi_tx,
    .mer_tx {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .prev,
    .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        width: 28%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin: auto;
        background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .next {
        background-position: 50% 150%;
    }

    .prev {
        background-position: 50% -50%;
    }
```

---

EDIT:

Inline Style Sheet for Table, TH, TD tags:

```
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <input type="text" name="timepicker1" size="70%" id="timepicker1" />
```

Comment: Have you checked Chrome Dev Tools? Sometimes when I go in there I get problems from the 'User Agent Stylesheet'. Basically, a set of pre-defined styles set into browsers. You would see this listed in the styles pane instead of the fine name and line number.

Comment: Please show some part of code you expect to be responsible for this time picker appearence.

Comment: @tdrsam - I see the "vertical-align: inherited" for the <td> tag in the user agent stylesheet.  Is there anyway to override this stylesheet?

Comment: @chem1st I've updated the original post with the CSS code that is used on the time picker.  Any changes I can make to override the "vertical-align" property in the user agent style sheet for the <td> tag?

Comment: Everything is just fine here. Show you table styles (`table`, `tr`, `td`). It must be your table styles (`td` preferably) limits the width of `timepicker_wrap`.

Comment: @chem1st I noticed that if I change the size of the time picker field to 70%, the time picker goes back to displaying horizontally (the correct way), but it ruins the formatting of the table.  I've added the code to the original post.  Any ideas on how to remove the size restrictions just for the time_picker?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you be able to whip together a jsfiddle/demo of what you're experiencing so that we can better help? (i have failed to recreate it with the code given - probably because im missing a js library that youre utilizing)

Comment: @indubitablee I'm not entirely sure how to set it up in JSFiddle, but I have a test page setup that demonstrates the issue here: [link](http://storage.cairweb.org/test.php).  Will this work or should I go ahead and try to setup the JSFiddle?

Comment: @R.Kelly, that actually works, thanks, I'll be posting an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add a width to `<div class="timepicker_wrap"></div>`
if you add this, it should work:

```
.timepicker_wrap{
    width: 240px;
}
```

i think it was just a matter of not enough space in the `timepicker_wrap` container to be placed next to each other.

Comment: That was it, thank you!  I can't up-vote yet, but I've accepted your answer.  Hopefully, this will help someone else with a similar issue.  Thanks again!